# Easiest way to view puppet reports on pending (i.e., --noop) changes

Tags: unix, puppet, foreman

My Puppet environment consists of a master and numerous agents which are run manually via the invocation of puppet agent --test.

I am attempting to find the easiest (i.e., human readable, at-a-glance type reporting) way to view reports on what hosts have pending changes due based on the current puppet code stored on the master. To give some context, I basically want to confirm that changes I have pushed to my Master will only be applied to specific hosts -- a sanity check, in a way.

I believe a console such as The Foreman may be of help here but would appreciate any other suggestions that fellow Puppet users can offer. I'm aware of the capabilities of the pe-console but cannot pursue this option.

Comment: Why not using Foreman? Seems like the perfect fit for your use case - http://theforeman.org/ . You can disable any options (provisioning etc..) you don't plan to use in the installer

Comment: You can cache the catalogs on the master and verify (the lack of) changes using `puppet master --compile <node>` and a catalog diff tool.

Answer (score 0):

TheForeman would certainly work, as would the Puppet Enterprise console. Those are the two interfaces that I normally would use. It would be considered running puppet in "audit" mode rather than (active?) mode. However, a word of advice, running `puppet agent --test` will apply changes if you do not have a `--noop` on the command line or somewhere in the puppet.conf. Please see http://nrvale0.github.io/blog/2014/04/10/the-basics-of-puppet-noop/ as an example of different ways to enable noop mode.